# How to enable this automatic line break feature in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am learning JavaScript through some tutorials on Udemy. The tutor in the videos is teaching chaining methods in arrays and as soon as he saves the code, the code gets formatted neatly as you can see in the image. Each method goes into a separate line automatically. This is just one instance and such smart formatting is happening throughout the code at various instances. How do I do this?

I tried the **Alt + Z** and everything that keeps coming up when I search for a solution for this problem. But I am not getting any solution anywhere. Maybe I am putting incorrect keywords because I don't know what this feature is actually called. Someone please help. I have to manually press Enter at every step and have to format my code so that it looks clean. It's time consuming.

[IMAGE](https://imgur.com/a/tL6sdhC)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the tutorial you are using on udemy would be using VS Code. And there is very famous extension called **Prettier**. You should install it and restart the IDE.

Also you might need to change the formatted settings. But first try this and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

**You need a formatter like `Prettier`**. You can install it directly via the VS Code Extensions tab. Then you can set up several configurations for changing the behavior of how prettier formats your code. These configurations belong in your user settings, which you can access via `CMD` + `,` -> `click the little icon` in the **top right corner** of VS Code to [open the user settings in Json View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0LsG.png)

****Example Settings****

```json
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode", // sets prettier as default formatter
"prettier.enable": true, // enables prettier
"prettier.tabWidth": 2, // define the tab width
"prettier.trailingComma": "es5", // automatically adds a commas where they are supposed to be, based on the JavaScript ES5 Syntax
```

And there are many many different settings, that you can explore, in VS Code when hovering over one, it also explains what the setting is doing.

I can also recommend having a look at [this one](https://glitteringkatie.com/posts/katies-vscode-cheatsheet). It's really beginner-friendly.

**Happy Coding :)**